# Fill entire row with same name

Tags: r, copy, rows

I am using r and I need to fill an entire row in my data frame with the same name. For example, the name in column A row 1 is red, while the other cells in the row are N/A. How do I copy the name red into the rest of the cells in the row, not the column.

Comment: `mydf[1,] <- "red"` would give your first row the word "red"

Answer (score -1):

You can get row wise location and assign value 'red' to it like :

```
df.loc[0] = 'red'
```

that's it

Comment: This is using python, which language you are using?

Comment: im sorry, I am using r

Comment: You can use this :
`df[r,] <- 'red'`
r would be row number